# Что означают разные названия государств?

Tags: лексика, названия

1. Для примера возьмем название  «ГЕРМАНИЯ», которое  в новейшей истории использовалось в официальных названиях государств в трех видах:
    А) Германская Демократическая Республика (согласованное определение),
    Б) Федеративная Республика  Германии (несогласованное определение), 
    В) Федеративная Республика  Германия (приложение перед именем собственным).
2. Справочная информация

В СССР использовалось на русском языке название «Федеративная Республика Германии». После присоединения в 1990 году Германской Демократической Республики к Федеративной Республике Германия было принято решение по взаимной договорённости правительств Германии и России не склонять слово «Германия» в официальном названии государства. Правильно: «Федеративная Республика Германия».

1. Кажется, что три формы имеют  одинаковое значение, но  тогда почему  было внесено это изменение?  Также: почему мы  говорим «Российская Республика», «Российская Федерация»,  но не говорим  «Республика Россия»? Может быть, всё-таки есть оттенки смыслового различия в этих названиях?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что дело в том, что с официальной точки зрения у государства может быть одно или несколько названий, но жестко закрепленных за ним. А как в народе уже называют - это другое дело.

Касательно того, чем отличаются "Федеративная Республика Германии" и "Федеративная Республика Германия", то у меня есть подозрение, что тут идет разграничение между разными периодами существования одного государства. Например, про Российскую республику (именно в контексте государства) можно говорить в определенном интервале 1917 г. А ныне существует Российская Федерация, она же - Россия. Ну, или мы можем говорить про российскую модель республики - российская республика, но тогда речь идет не о государстве как таковом, а о его типаже.

Разница же между ГДР и ФРГ очевидна, т.к. это были совершенно разные гос-ва.

Answer (score 0):

> решение по взаимной договорённости правительств Германии и России не склонять слово «Германия»

София, оно Вам надо этот бред из Вики копипастиить?
Это раньше было несколняемое "Германии" по всех падежах, в в современном варианте, если верить этому афонаризму, надо бы как раз склонять (типа "договор между Российской федерацией и Федеративной Республикой Германией"). Слава богу, что никто этого все равно не делает, поскольку такие топонимы с родовым словом обычно не склоняются. Последний факт, собственно, все и объясняет.

Что касается послевоенного варианта, то его объяснение весьма спорно. Я не думаю, что в том были какие-то политические изыскания, скорее всего - элементарная неграмотность при переводе, узаконенная авторитетом власти предержащей. 
Это вам не "Юнайтед стэйс оф таки Америка".

Comment: Так жаль, что не получается согласиться с Вами. Этот топоним обычно СКЛОНЯЕТСЯ, например:"Главная цель  – познакомиться с Федеративной Республикой Германией ". "Какие бывают визы для въезда в Федеративную Республику Германию"? Но в том же тексте: "Въезд в страну определенного лица имеет особенное значение для Федеративной Республики Германия". Так надо склонять или нет современное название? А вы его склоняете? И прежнее название вряд ли можно отнести к элементарной неграмотности.  Федеративная республика просто не могла использовать топоним  "Германия", так как была только частью Германии.

Comment: @София,

> Федеративная республика просто не могла использовать топоним "Германия", так как была только частью Германии.

Ну, это вообще не аргумент, т.к. германских государств все время было больше одного (та же Австрия, например).

Comment: Мы же не о германских народах говорим, а о конкретном топониме "Германия", который только что был названием единого государства и который странно было бы относить к его части. А после восстановления государства было восстановлено и общее название. Родительный падеж в сочетании "Федеративная республика Германии" говорит нам о том, что это только часть страны "Германия".

Comment: Весьма логично! ГДР надо было бы назвать ДРГ (Демократическая Республика Германии), для симметрии)

Comment: >Этот топоним обычно СКЛОНЯЕТСЯ, например:"Главная цель – познакомиться с Федеративной Республикой Германией "  
  
Звечит примерно как "с республикой Украиной" или "с государством Израилем". Я таки имел в виду грамотных людей, которые названия государств не склоняются при родовом слове.   
  
Но не в этом дело. Если принять Вашу версию и склонять, то о чем тогда, простите, договорились в 1990 г.?

Comment: В ваших примерах - приложение + имя собственное (неофициальное название), а мы говорим о составном имени собственном, которое является официальным названием государства.  А разница вот какая: Федеративная Республика Германии - с Федеративной Республикой Германии и Федеративная Республика Германия - с Федеративной Республикой Германией. Здесь уже не разговоры грамотных людей, а необходимость сделать правильную запись в документах.